# Was the boar killed by Lord Indra in Brahmanas same as Lord Varaha?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, avatars, varaha

According to [this source](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=b7Meabtj8mcC&pg=PA41&dq=veda+boar&hl=it&sa=X&ei=1uIyVMHnG8jXyQOo9oDoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=veda%20boar&f=false), there is a story in Brahmanas where Lord Indra kills a boar who has stolen the treasure of the asuras, then gives its carcass to Lord Vishnu, who offers it as a sacrifice to the gods.

It further states that the story has been retold in Charaka Samhita where the boar is described as a form of Prajāpati, and is credited with having raised the earth from the primeval waters, and that the same boar is described as an avatar of Lord Vishnu (Varaha) in Mahabharat and Ramayan.

I'm skeptical about this translated version, especially since it is from 1897, a period notorious for incorrect and biased translations by colonialists.

So I wanted to ask, are these two boars the same? Do we have any more information in original texts?

Comment: The boar incarnation of Vishnu and boar that Indra kills are two different beings.

Comment: @Anubhav Jha What are your sources for that?

Comment: The translation of `Varaha` is also `rain clouds` and many translators have translated `Rig Veda 1.61.7` in terms of rain clouds.