# Does Siva kill Varaha?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, reference-request

I recall reading that lord Siva killed Varaha, Visnu's boar incarnation. Is it true?  Is this in any scripture?  Apparently, Narad, the sage, took offense seeing the mother suckling her cubs. Somehow Siva got word of this and soon after he killed the mother (I assume with his trident). This is followed by Visnu reappearing - like the genie from Aladdin I guess - laughing off the whole thing, knowing his boar incarnation is just maya.  Is there a source for this story?

note: there is another question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26706/was-the-boar-killed-by-lord-indra-in-brahmanas-same-as-lord-varaha) about lord Indra killing a boar, but I'm not sure if it's the same incidence.

Comment: is this -1 just b/c of my past reputation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.;

Sharabha Upanishad 13.:

> Let there be adoration to that Rudra, who, the ancient Lord, the one who killed the terrible and troublesome incarnations of Vishnu, namely, Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narasimha, and Vamana; and the one who troubled Suresha (Indra) by making him tired and who reduced Manmata (Kama) and Yama into ashes.

~ Skanda Purāṇam Shankar Samhita, Virmahendra Khanda, 2.41-42.:

> Matsya's eyes, Kurma's bones, Varaha's teeth, Narasimha's skin, and Vamana's vertebral column , were all seized by Lord Shiva after they were liberated by him.

You can check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54995/20968) and [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56953/20968) for the Sharabha-Varaha episode from Sri Kalika Puran and the views of Jagat Guru Sri Adi Shankaracharya on it.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: What the hell why the hell did he kill the supreme lord?

Comment: Tamasic puranas Shiva is AdiVishnu Bhakta

Comment: Because of their animalistic behaviour after infusing in those forms. That's the hell why it was done.

Comment: No all Vishnu avatars are in total control and afterwards they go back to Narayana.

Comment: C'mon man, even i can say Vishnu is Adi Shiva Bhakta. So, stop this nonsense and write ur own answer indeed tamsik purana rajasik purana sattvik purana are different according to different puranas.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case but u r free to believe whatever u want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151009/discussion-between-haridasa-and-sri-shiva-charanam-dsa-vishnu).

Comment: @Haridasa texts of every sect has stories like this. Even there are Vaishnava agama texts which have stories like narasimha killing shiva which would be disturbing to Saivites the same way Sharabha story is for vaishnavites

Comment: Sharabha is a upanishadic and pauranic event in shaiva agamas to many many such incidents are present. Anyways, guys talk privately somewhere else in a chat or something, not under my answer, cz i am unnecessarily getting notifications. And it's both disturbing and irritating. Prd. Goodbye..